# Django-ORM: distinct is needed. Why?

Tags: django, django-orm

I am playing around with django ORM

```
import django
django.setup()
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.db.models import Count

# All users
print(User.objects.all().count())
# --> 742

# Should be: All users which are in a group.
# But the result is different. I don't understand this.
print(User.objects.filter(groups__in=Group.objects.all()).count())
# --> 1731

# All users which are in a group.
# distinct needed
print(User.objects.filter(groups__in=Group.objects.all()).distinct().count())
# --> 543

# All users which are in a group. Without distinct, annotate seems to do this.
print(User.objects.filter(groups__in=Group.objects.all()).annotate(Count('pk')).count())
# --> 543

# All users which are in no group
print(User.objects.filter(groups__isnull=True).count())
# --> 199

# 199 + 543 = 742  (nice)
```

I don't understand the second query which returns 1731.

I know that I can use distinct().

Nevertheless 1731 looks like a bug to me.

What is the intention why below query is not distinct/unique?

```
User.objects.filter(groups__in=Group.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `User.groups` is a `ForeignKey` or some other relationship that associates each `User` with zero to many `Group` instances.

So the query which confuses you:

```python
User.objects.filter(groups__in=Group.objects.all())
```

That query can be described as:

- Access the `Group` model manager (`Group.objects`).
- Make a `QuerySet`:

  - Return all `Group` instances (`Group.objects.all()`).
- Access the `User` model manager (`User.objects`).
- Make a `Queryset`:

  - Join to the `Group` model, on the `User.groups` foreign key.
  - Return every (`User` + `Group`) row which has an associated `Group`.

That is not “all users which are in a group”; instead, it is “All user–group pairs where the group exists”.

By querying on *each of* the multiple-value `User.groups` field, **you are implying that the query must contain a join** from `User` to `Group` rows.

---

Instead, you want:

- Access the `User` model manager (`User.objects`).
- Make a `QuerySet`:

  - Return all rows which have `groups` not empty.

```python
User.objects.filter(groups__isnull=False)
```

Note that this – “All users which have a non-empty set of associated groups” – is the inverse of another example query you have (“All users which are in no group”).

Answer (score 6):

Raw MySQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT user.id, group.id FROM user LEFT JOIN group ON user.group_id = group.id
```

The result will contain all possible combinations of users and groups and I guess some users belong to more than one group.

Comment: Yes, the result is a LEFT JOIN. I am searching the **intention** why things are like they are.

Comment: Django always uses LEFT JOIN because it is possible to add conditions like `User.objects.filter(groups=None)` or even `User.objects.filter(groups__deparment__manager=None)`

Comment: But the reason is not a `LEFT JOIN` but multiple groups for each user.

Comment: To add to that, you were simply querying for the wrong thing. If you want to know how many users are in a group, `User.objects.exclude(groups__isnull=True).count()` provides the answer. As Raz has said, you were querying for the total combinations of users and groups. That's two different things to query for.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to fetch all users from all groups, but a user can present in multiple groups that's why **distinct** is required. if you want users ina specific group instead of doing an **all** try a **filter** query.

Answer (score 2):

Since groups is a `ManyToManyField` the query translated into `INNER JOIN` statement.

If you print the following you will see the query generated by the `QuerySet`:

```
>>> print(User.objects.filter(groups__in=Group.objects.all()).query)
SELECT `auth_user`.`id`,  .... , `auth_user`.`date_joined` FROM `auth_user` INNER JOIN `auth_user_groups` ON (`auth_user`.`id` = `auth_user_groups`.`user_id`) WHERE `auth_user_groups`.`group_id` IN (SELECT `auth_group`.`id` FROM `auth_group`)
```

As you would see the query joins `auth_user` and `auth_user_groups` tables. 
Where `auth_user_groups` is the `ManyToManyField` table not the table for `Group` model. Thus a user will come more than once.

You would want to use `annotate` get users having grous, in my case the numbers are following:

```
$ ./manage.py shell
>>> 
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
>>> from django.db.models import Count
>>>
# All users
>>> print(User.objects.all().count())
556
>>>
# All users which are not in a group.
>>> print(User.objects.annotate(group_count=Count('groups')).filter(group_count=0).count())
44
>>>
# All users which are in a group.
>>> print(User.objects.annotate(group_count=Count('groups')).filter(group_count__gt=0).count())
512
>>>
```

Annotate is similar to distinct in behaviour. It creates a `group by` query. You can see and inspect the query as following.

```
>>> print(User.objects.annotate(group_count=Count('groups')).filter(group_count__gt=0).query)
SELECT `auth_user`.`id`, `auth_user`.`password`, `auth_user`.`last_login`, `auth_user`.`is_superuser`, `auth_user`.`username`, `auth_user`.`first_name`, `auth_user`.`last_name`, `auth_user`.`email`, `auth_user`.`is_staff`, `auth_user`.`is_active`, `auth_user`.`date_joined`, COUNT(`auth_user_groups`.`group_id`) AS `group_count` FROM `auth_user` LEFT OUTER JOIN `auth_user_groups` ON (`auth_user`.`id` = `auth_user_groups`.`user_id`) GROUP BY `auth_user`.`id` HAVING COUNT(`auth_user_groups`.`group_id`) > 0 ORDER BY NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run a 'DISTINCT' query against a database you end up with a listing of each distinct row in the data results.  The reason that you have more 'DISTINCT' rows in your Django result is there is a combinatoric cross multiplication going on, creating extra results.

Other answers have mentioned all of this, but since you're asking the why:
The ORM, in this join, would probably allow you to pull fields attached to the group from the query. So if you wanted, say, all these users and all the groups and the group contact for some kind of massive weird mail merge, you could get them.

The post-processing brought on by DISTINCT is narrowing your results down according to the **fields you have pulled** rather than the rows in the query.  If you were to use the PyCharm debugger or something, you might find that the groups aren't as easy to access using various ORM syntax when you have the distinct as when you don't.